# How to playback asx files/streams with java

Tags: java, stream, playback, asx

I am trying to play a asx file with Java SE. I have read a lot of documentation of frameworks and libraries but I am unable to find a solution.

Is it at all possible to playback ASX files. If so, with what framework or librarie?

Thanks in advance,
Stefan NLD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=675666&start=90), it should be possible using [dsj](http://www.humatic.de/htools/dsj.htm) (DirectShow Java). Never tested personally.